# Deg $n$ integral polynomial $P(x)$ with $n+1$ integer solutions to $0\leq P\leq d$

Tags: polynomials

Let $d\in\mathbf{N}$ be as follows: there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ with degree $n>1$ and integer coefficients, such that $P$ has $n+1$ integer solutions to
\begin{equation*}
0\leq P(x) \leq d
\end{equation*}
What is the minimum possible value of $d$? What if $P$ has $n+2$ integer solutions?

Comment: Note that a trivial upper bound for $n+1$ solutions is $k!^2$ for even $n=2k$ and  $k!(k+1)!$ for $n=2k+1$. I wouldn't be too surprised if those bounds are sharp...

Comment: In fact we can do better sometimes. For $n=6$, take $P(x)=(1-x^2)(3-x^2)(9-x^2)$ then $d=27<36$. Fascinating problem!

Comment: For any such polynomial P, you can scale it with a large integer K. Then KP has fewer integer solutions to the given inequalities.  Gerhard "Just Stretch The Axis Some" Paseman, 2019.01.05.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: You are correct. I have modified the problem.

Comment: @Wolfgang: I checked $n=8$ and $P_8=(1-x^2)(3-x^2)(9-x^2)(16-x^2)$ seems optimal; also checked $n=10$ and $P_8(25-x^2)$ seems optimal. The factor $(16-x^2)$ cannot be changed to $(15-x^2)$ (for $15\cdot 13\cdot 7\cdot 9>3\cdot 9\cdot 16\cdot 25$). It seems $(3-x^2)$ is the only exception.

Comment: @Wolfgang: I checked $n=14$ and this time $(16-x^2)$ being changed to $(15-x^2)$ can improve $d$. Not sure if more and more $(4k^2-x^2)$ terms should be reduced by $1$ as even $n$ becomes larger. Not sure if it can be further reduced, either.

Comment: Even better: for $n=6$, take $x^2(4-x^2)(9-x^2)$ which yields $d=24$. Likewise for $n=8$, take $x^2(4-x^2)(9-x^2)(16-x^2)$, which is better than yours. The new upper bound for $n=2k$ is $d\le\prod_{j=2}^k(j^2-1)=(k-1)!(k+1)!/2$. I think generally there is still room for improvement somewhere. But I have the impression that the upper bounds of $O((\frac n2)!^2)$ are sharper than Ilya Bogdanov's lower bound.

Comment: Still better for $n=8$: $x^2(4-x^2)(8-x^2)(16-x^2)$ with $d=315<360$.

Comment: But $d=315$ for $n=8$ is exactly my lower bound!

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Sure enough :) For $n=10$, best I can find is $x^2(4-x^2)(8-x^2)(16-x^2)(25-x^2)$ with $d=7560>7087.5 $ (the latter is your lower bound).

Comment: @Wolfgang: Somehow, it seems to me that the bound may be achieved when it is integral. So I'm mostly interested now in $n=16$. I'll try to check it when I'll have a piece of paper in my hands, instead of a kid;).

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov Wish you good luck! Well, for $n=14$, [we can come very close to the lower bound](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5Bx%5E2(4-x%5E2)(+7-x%5E2)(+16-x%5E2)(+25-x%5E2)(+36-x%5E2)(+49-x%5E2)++%2F(14!%2F2%5E13),+%7Bx,+0,+3%7D%5D), up to a factor of $\frac{1024}{1001}\approx1.023$, whereas the same for $n=16$ only yields a factor $1.074$. A bit worse than $n=10$ (factor $1.067$) - but maybe after all, the truth is closer to your lower bound than to the upper one, at least for even $n$. Funny optimisation problem!

Comment: @Wolfgang: Thanks, I got that luck! For $n=16$ we have the minimal $d=16!/2^{!5}=638\,512\,875$ with a polynomial $P_{16}(x)=-x^2(x^2-4)(x^2-16)(x^2-36)(x^2-64)(x^6-80x^4+1684x^2-8040)$. Double check is very welcome...

Comment: Wow, correct. Neat and clever! Now I see that @GerhardPaseman's comment about stretching has some usefulness as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_0<\dots<x_n$ be the points where small values $y_0,\dots,y_n$ are attained. By Lagrange's interpolation formula, the number
$$
  \sum_{i=0}^n y_i\cdot\left(\prod_{j\neq i} (x_i-x_j)\right)^{-1}
\qquad(*)
$$
is a nonzero integer $p$, as it is the leading coefficient of $P$. This yields an easy lower bound for the maximum of the $y_i$, as the inverse to the sum of a half of the coefficients in $(*)$ (even or odd ones, depending on the sign of $p$).

This bound is minimal when $x_i=i$, and in this case both bounds equal $ n!/2^{n-1}$. Hence this is a total lower bound. It seems to differ from the upper bound mentioned by @Wolfgang in the comment by a factor of $\Theta(\sqrt n)$.

On the other hand, perhaps, this bound may even be (almost) achieved, especially when it is integral (which happens when $n$ is a power of 2)?

Comment: Yes asymptotically they differ by $\frac18\sqrt{2\pi n}\approx .31\sqrt{ n} $.

Comment: You may want to add the construction you found, as it generalizes indeed for $n=2^k$, just by Lagrange interpolation for the odd values $P(-n+1)=P(-n+3)=\cdots=P(n-1)=d$ between the even ones $P(-n)=P(-n+2)=\cdots=P(n)=0$. It is easy to see from the factors of $d$ that the coefficients must be integers. E.g. for $n=32$, it is $ -x^2(x^2-4)\cdots (x^2-16^2  )(x^{14} - 672x^{12} + 174200x^{10} - 22119856x^8 + 1443224772x^6 - 46275602672x^4 + 625295296152x^2 - 2334623374800)$.

Comment: @Wolfgang: I've learned from Maple that the coefficients are integer, but I'm still thinking on how to prove that... My trouble is with powers of 2 only.

Comment: Right, I neglected those. Empirically, if for $n=2^k$ the last factor is denoted $(a_{2^{k-1}} x^{2^k-2}+a_{2^{k-1}-1} x^{2^k-4}\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1)$, then the 2-valuations of the coefficients seem to be $\nu_2(a_i)=k-\nu_2(i)$ for all except the leading and the next one. Thus an even stronger conjecture (checked till $k=8$), but I don't know if that helps.